# What information is contained in Isle of Man birth, marriage, and death certificates?

Tags: vital-records, civil-registration, isle-of-man

Today I discovered a relative who was born on the Isle of Man. I am considering ordering her birth certificate, which got me wondering about what would actually be on it.

It appears civil registration in the Isle of Man was independent of civil registration in the other countries of the UK. There are a number of differences between BMD certificates from England & Wales compared to those from Scotland or Ireland. For example, see the previous question titled: [UK death certificate details in 1908](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/10223/uk-death-certificate-details-in-1908).

What fields are given on a birth, marriage, and death certificate from the Isle of Man? What are the differences compared to other countries of the UK? Has the content of BMD certificates changed since the start of civil registration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a useful guide here:
https://www.manxbmd.com/records.html

The only example I have obtained is for a birth (1946) and on that the information is exactly what I would expect from a register entry in England/Wales of the same era.